# Maximal solution and interval of differential equation $y'=y\ln(1+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry for my bad english.

Let the differential equation defined by  $\begin{cases}
y'=y\ln(1+y)  \\ 
y(0) = a > -1\end{cases}$.

We want to find the maximal solution defined on the maximal interval $J$.
We can notice that $u_1=0$ is a maximal solution.

Let an other solution $(u_2,J)$ distinct of $u_1$. Then $\forall x \in J, u_2(x)>0$ OR $-1<u_2(x)<0$.
In the second case, I found that $J=\mathbb{R}$ because $u_2$ is bounded.

In the first case, $\inf(J) = -\infty$ because $u_2$ is incrasing and bounded from below.

But how to study $\sup(J)$ ? Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Note that $u_1\equiv 0$ is a solution if and only if $a=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y(x)>0$ for all $x\in J$ then $y(x)\ln(1+y(x))\le (1+y(x))\ln(1+y(x))$ and so $$\frac{1}{(1+y(x))\ln(1+y(x))}y'(x)\le 1.$$
Since $a>0$, integrating both sides you get
$$ \ln(\ln(1+y(x)))-\ln(\ln(1+a))\le x,$$
which gives  $$1+y(x)\le e^{\ln(1+a)e^{x}}.$$In particular, if $J$ is bounded from above, then so is $y$ but then, since it is increasing, there exists $$\lim_{x\to\sup J}y(x)=\ell<\infty$$ which is a contradiction since we could extend $y$ by considering the initial value problem $y(\sup J)=\ell$. Thus $J=\mathbb {R}.$

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's very clear !